# VBA Multiple Criteria / Variable Filter

Tags: vba, variables, excel, filter

I need some help regarding filtering in excel, and would greatly appreciate any assistance.
I would like to be able to filter by variable criteria, and possibly by multiple variable criteria.
Allow me to explain this as simple as I possibly can

I have a workbook, in Sheet 2 I have data. In Sheet 1, I have a list of variables which I need to be filtered in sheet 2. These variables will vary in quantity, and of course the data in each cell will vary.

Now here is where I have my humble request(s).

Can I possibly have code for two separate functions:

1) For excel to register how many variables there are, and to filter each of these variables one by one (I have code that will do what I require and then reset the filter).

2) For excel to register the variables and filter all of them at the same time (multiple criteria).

I have attached a link to an example excel spreadsheet. I hope it helps!

http://www.filedropper.com/excelexample

I really appreciate any help on this.

Thank You

Comment: First iterate over the list, create a collection of dictionary of unique values, then iterate over that collection, applying each as a filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this small example, we gather the values from the Info tab, remove any blanks and apply that filter to the first column of the Data tab so all matches will be displayed:

```
Sub luxation()
    Dim sh1 As Worksheet, N As Long
    Dim st As String
    Set sh1 = Sheets("Info")
    N = sh1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To N
        v = sh1.Cells(i, 1).Value
        If v <> "" Then
            st = st & v & ","
        End If
    Next i
    st = Mid(st, 1, Len(st) - 1)
    Arr1 = Split(st, ",")

    Sheets("Data").AutoFilterMode = False
    With Sheets("Data").Range("$A$1:$C$9244")
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Arr1, Operator:=xlFilterValues
    End With
End Sub
```

In the next example, the filter values are applied sequentially:

```
Sub luxation2()
    Dim sh1 As Worksheet, N As Long
    Dim st As String
    Set sh1 = Sheets("Info")
    N = sh1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To N
        v = sh1.Cells(i, 1).Value
        If v <> "" Then
            st = st & v & ","
        End If
    Next i
    st = Mid(st, 1, Len(st) - 1)
    Arr1 = Split(st, ",")
    Sheets("Data").Activate
    For i = LBound(Arr1) To UBound(Arr1)
        Sheets("Data").AutoFilterMode = False
        With Sheets("Data").Range("$A$1:$C$9244")
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Arr1(i), Operator:=xlFilterValues
        End With
        MsgBox "Check out the filter"
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi,  I have another question. If possible your help would be appreciated. I created a macro for my colleague in France using the filter macros you helped me with (above), and it seems to error on the following line (error code 5) : st = Mid(st, 1, Len(st) - 1)    They are using a French version of excel. It works fine for me, so I think it may be a language issue. Thank you for your help!

Comment: First make sure **MID** and **LEN** are valid in French **VBA**.  Then make sure **st** has something in it!!

Comment: Hi, I checked online and it would appear that MID and LEN are not valid in french, so I replaced them with the french functions (NBCAR and STXT), http://en.excel-translator.de/mid/ and http://en.excel-translator.de/len/ . However it now displays an error "Sub or function not defined" and highlights "NBCAR" in the line : st = STXT(st, 1, NBCAR(st) - 1) . There are values in st, so i'm not sure what to do next. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank You!